# Something error when copying text using clipboard.js

Tags: javascript, html, clipboard.js

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/clipboard@2/dist/clipboard.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn" data-clipboard-text="text">
    Copy to clipboard
</button>
```

Nothing is copied when I click the button.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: I'm just wanting to copy the words "text" by clicking the button.

Comment: Okay, I don't think you need to use a npm module for that purpose.
You can use the navigator API to achieve the same results. 
Just call  function that executes this code `navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText)` 
here copyText is the Text that you want to copy to your clipboard. To learn more about it visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText

Answer (score 0):

> you need to instantiate it by passing a DOM selector, HTML element, or list of HTML elements.

```
new ClipboardJS('.btn');
```

https://clipboardjs.com/#setup